# Cómo usar PHP para afectar el estilo de CSS

Tags: php, css

Estoy intentando meter una condición para cambiar el fondo de un elemento HTML dependiendo el id que se inserte a la tabla. Quiero usar una condición para que cuando la variable coincida con el id que le corresponda al estilo de un fondo que tengo en mi carpeta img.

¿Es posible usar condiciones(if/else) en PHP que afecten el estilo de CSS? Usando variables de una tabla de mysql. ¿Existe otra manera de hacer esa función con los fondos y las variables de id?

Esto es lo que tengo en mente hasta el momento:

```php
<?php

header("Content-Type: text/css; charset: UTF-8")

if($id == 1){
    .formix{
        background-image: url(../img/azul.jpg);
    }
}
else if($id == 2){
    .formix{
        background-image: url(../img/cafe.jpg);
    }
}
else if($id == 3){
    .formix{
        background-image: url(../img/morado.jpg);
    }
}
else if($id == 4){
    .formix{
        background-image: url(../img/naranja.jpg);
    }
}
else if($id == 5){
    .formix{
        background-image: url(../img/rojo.jpg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Si es posible... el codigo debe ir como texto, no como imagen...

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow , te recomiendo que realices el [tour] y leas [ask] para mejorar tu pregunta y te podamos apoyar. Presiona en [edit] y agrega el código en vez de la imagen del código.

Comment: Creo que lo más conveniente sería tener un archivo CSS estático, con clases diferentes para cada color y, cuando generes el contenido, asignas la clase que corresponda al ID.

Comment: Yo diría más bien que tenga un conjunto de reglas CSS definidas y solo cambie los nombres de clases con PHP al cambiar su `$id`. Y en lugar de colocarlo en una condicional, mejor sería crear una colección (tipo diccionario) donde por el número del `$id` obtenga los nombres de las clases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hice el ejemplo que buscas, simplemente aplicado directamente al body.

Pero tal y como menciona Triby, sería mejor tener un CSS estático.
Pero quizás y esto te ayude a entender que SI puedes usar el php para aplicar lo que quieras.

```
<?php
$id1 = 1;
$id2 = 2;
$id3 = 1;
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body style="margin: 0px;">
    <div style="width: 100vw; height: 33vh;
        <?php
        if ($id1 == 1) { //SE aplica
            echo "background-color: red;";
        }
        ?>
    ">
    </div>
    <div style="width: 100vw; height: 33vh;
        <?php
        if ($id2 == 1) { //Blue no se aplica por no cumplir condicion
            echo "background-color: blue;";
        }
        ?>
    ">
    </div>
    <div style="width: 100vw; height: 33vh;
        <?php
        if ($id3 == 1) { //Se aplica
            echo "background-color: green;";
        }
        ?>
    ">
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: muchas gracias por la respuesta

Answer (score 2):

Para que sea más fácil de mantener, y como parece que los colores son fijos dependiendo del ID, te recomendaría tener todos las combinaciones en CSS (no parecen muchas) y luego aplicar una única clase al `body` de tu página (o al contenedor). Luego, deja que sea el navegador el que se encargue de hacer el trabajo.

En CSS tendrías algo como esto:

```css
.id1 .formix{
  background-image: url(../img/azul.jpg);
}

.id2 .formix{
  background-image: url(../img/cafe.jpg);
}

.id3 .formix{
  background-image: url(../img/morado.jpg);
}

.id4 .formix{
  background-image: url(../img/naranja.jpg);
}

.id5 .formix{
  background-image: url(../img/rojo.jpg);
}
```

Y luego en la página, una vez hayas leído el valor del id desde la base de datos, pondría la clase en el contenedor del elemento que va a tener dentro a formix:

```xml
<div class="id<?php echo $id; ?>">
  <div class="formix">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Es una solución interesante